# SAP table structure to proceed passing by table by XML

Tags: json, xml, abap, azure-logic-apps, saprfc

I've created Logic App in Azure which has some json data inside. I'd like to connect to SAP system and pass parameters to an ABAP Function Module via RFC.
RFC input parameters in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ZFM_MGR_RFC xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Rfc/">
<INVOICE_ID>WZ</INVOICE_ID>
<ITEMS>[
{"Amount":"28 511,40","Description":"Podstawowy podatek VAT 23%"},
{"Amount":"6 145,20","Description":"Podatek VAT 8%"}
]</ITEMS> 
 </ZFM_MGR_RFC>
```

ABAP FM definition:

```
FUNCTION ZFM_MGR_RFC
  IMPORTING
    VALUE(INVOICE_ID) TYPE STRING OPTIONAL
    VALUE(ITEMS) TYPE ZRFC_TT_INVOICE_ITEMS OPTIONAL.
```

ABAP Structure:
[image]
ABAP Table type:
[image]
Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "GeneralBadRequest",
    "message": "Failed to process request. Error details: 'Under expected node type 'Text' for element '' with local name '', expected row start element with local name 'ZRFC_TT_INVOICE_ITEMS' or 'ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS' with namespace '', or end element from parent node.'.",
    "target": ""
  }
}
```

According to this error I just simply need to change ITEMS type to STRING and It will work, but I don't want to make post-processing string and creating from it an array inside abap FM.

I need to create a structure and table type in ABAP which will work with this data. Does anybody has an idea how can I deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are asking how to create a structure or a table type in ABAP, it's transaction code `SE11`. But you probably found it yourself. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: `RFC input parameters in XML` if you already have working RFC function module in SAP backend, probably you already have all the structures. The question is how to save this data to DB or how to pass it to FM?

Comment: The question is which fields should I create in structure to pass Items to FM without any problems. I can't declare Type standard table in FM for Items. I need exact fields.

Comment: @SandraRossi 
I've edited my post. I think it explains the problem better than it used to be. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Suncatcher The question is how can I match structures from logic apps and sap FM?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ITEMS element is a table and the XML schema expected XML row elements to follow. But instead you have JSON text.

Use the Logic App action Generate Schema to fetch the XML schema for your customer RFC.

Refer to table RFC XML sample in the public documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-sap-connector#xml-samples-for-rfc-requests

In particular:

```xml
<STFC_WRITE_TO_TCPIC xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Rfc/">
   <RESTART_QNAME>exampleQName</RESTART_QNAME>
   <TCPICDAT>
      <ABAPTEXT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Rfc/">
         <LINE>exampleFieldInput1</LINE>
      </ABAPTEXT>
      <ABAPTEXT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Rfc/">
         <LINE>exampleFieldInput2</LINE>
      </ABAPTEXT>
      <ABAPTEXT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Rfc/">
         <LINE>exampleFieldInput3</LINE>
      </ABAPTEXT>
   </TCPICDAT>
</STFC_WRITE_TO_TCPIC>
```

TCPICDAT is the table element.
ABAPTEXT are example of row elements.
LINE are example of field elements within a row.

As per your screenshot, your row type is ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS so must be named the row elements. AMOUNT and DESCRIPTION appear to be your fields.

So your XML needs to look something like:

```xml
<ITEMS>
  <ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/">
    <AMOUNT>28 511,40</AMOUNT>
    <DESCRIPTION>Podstawowy podatek VAT 23%</DESCRIPTION>
  </ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS>
  <ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/">
    <AMOUNT>6 145,20</AMOUNT>
    <DESCRIPTION>Podatek VAT 8%</DESCRIPTION>
  </ZRFC_ST_INVOICE_ITEMS>
</ITEMS>
```

Finally, you can also use the XML validation action prior to sending a payload to SAP action, so you can check that your XML payload is conforming to the XML schema for the specific RFC.